# ViewPager and RecyclerView with itemTouchHelper

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, swipe

I have the strcutur of views:
MainActiviry

```
-----Fragmet
-------------ViewPager
--------------------Fragment1 с RecyclerView
--------------------Fragment2 с RecyclerView
--------------------Fragment2 с RecyclerView
```

Every RecyclerView has itemTouchHelper.
The problem is that swipe triggers either a swipe ViewOager or swipe Item. But I need  like on the main page Goggle play market. Swipe on item triggered swipe on item, swipe on emty space beetwen item triggered swipe PagerView.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) again and revise your question. Your post neither contains an actual question nor makes it clear, what your problem is and what kind of a solution you expect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable ViewPager paging when child recyclerview scrolls to last item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38466413/disable-viewpager-paging-when-child-recyclerview-scrolls-to-last-item)

Comment: Yes it partly solves the problem. But also i need ViewPager can swipe page if i touch on empty spaces beetwen items.