# Scroll issues with LazyRow inside traditional android ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

When using the jetpack compose interoperability API, using LazyRow inside a prebuilt ViewPager causes scroll issues.

**When trying to scroll items inside the LazyRow the ViewPager moves. Is there any way we can prevent this?**

ComposeView

```
<androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/compose_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Setting the view in the fragment

```
binding.composeView.setContent {
    HorizontalScrollableView(listOfCards)
}
```

And the view written in compose

```
@Composable
fun HorizontalScrollableView(listOfCards: List<Cards>) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(color = colorResource(R.color.grey10))
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Items",
            color = colors.primary,
            style = typography.subheadBold,
            fontSize = 15.sp,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp, top = 10.dp, end = 16.dp)
        )
        LazyRow(contentPadding = PaddingValues(end = 16.dp)) {
            items(
                items = listOfCards,
                key = { listOfCards.id }
            ) {
                RenderCard(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any news about this issue? @akash-amin

Comment: I believe the simplest solution would be migrating from ViewPager to compose `Pager` and using `AndroidView`s (or `AndroidViewBinding`s) for traditional views.

Comment: Are you using ViewPager2 or just ViewPager? If it's ViewPager2 then I'd suggest to disable manual drag/scroll if it's feasible for you.

Comment: Here's the [compose pager doc](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/) in the accompanist library.

Answer (score 2):

This is mainly because ComposeView is not implementing `canScrollHorizontally` correctly. `ViewPager` uses this method to decide whether it intercepts touch events.

A workaround:

Create a class extending `FrameLayout`, override `canScrollHorizontally` to always return true, and wrap `ComposeView` with this container. In this way, the scrolling in `ComposeView` works normally. The shortcoming of this workaround is that the `ViewPager` won't scroll if you are moving your finger on `ComposeView`, even when `ComposeView` has scrolled to the end.

Answer (score 1):

It is a normal behavior you experience.The similar problem is described here.

[Link](https://github.com/google/accompanist/issues/347)

Alternatively, lazy row gestures can be controlled.

```
Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
    detectTapGestures(
        onPress = { /* Called when the gesture starts */ },
        onDoubleTap = { /* Called on Double Tap */ },
        onLongPress = { /* Called on Long Press */ },
        onTap = { /* Called on Tap */ }
    )
}
```

In onPress you can cancel the scroll state you want

Apart from composing, we were solving it this way.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38466413/disable-viewpager-paging-when-child-recyclerview-scrolls-to-last-item/39272625)

I hope this helps. Good job